# can't get mapping details for edmx

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a quick table with editable roles for a website.

[image]

Which looks like this.

I created 2 tables

```
  HINames
  [Id][Name][HI][GW][White][WY][Yellow]

 HandicapIndex
 [Id][RevisionDate]
```

I can't get these to map to each other under navigation properties, nor is there an updated code or table letting me pass values to it.

Comment: The problem is that you have no Foreign Key from your HandicapIndex table to your HINames table.

Comment: @ajliptak ok so let's say I add `[RevisionDate]` to `HINames`. Then what.

Comment: No, don't do that, as that's not unique, what you need is this:

HINames
  [Id][Name][HI][GW][White][WY][Yellow]

 HandicapIndex
 [Id][RevisionDate][HiNamesId]